# How to find integer solutions of the equation $x(x+9)=y(y+6)$ where x,y are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I found that the equation becomes $$(2x+9)^2-(2y+6)^2=45$$. And $45 = 9^2-6^2 = 7^2-{2^2}$. From here I found these solutions $(x,y)=(0,0), \ (0,-6), \ (-9,0),\ (-9,-6),\ (-1,-2),\ (-1, 4), \ (-8,-2), \ (-8,-4)$.

Does this equation has finite numbers of integer solutions and what would be better approach to solve such problems?

Comment: $\;(-8,-4)\;$ isn't a solution, for example...nor is $\;(-9,0)\;$ , say.

Comment: Your first transformation is equivalent to $x(x + 9) = y(y + 6)$, rather than the equation in your title. Is that a mistake in your working or a typo in your title?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I mistakenly replaced 9 with 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation in the title (which is different from the one in your text) can be written as
$$(x^2-y^2)+6(x-y)=0 \implies (x-y)(x+y+6)=0.$$
Now either $x=y$ or $x+y+6=0$.

So it has solutions as $\{(a,a) \, | \, a \in \Bbb{Z}\} \cup \{(a,-6-a)\, |\, a \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

**After you modified your original problem**

The equation can be written as
$$(2x+2y+15)(2x-2y+3)=45.$$
Now factor $45=ab$ and solve the system
\begin{align*}
2x+2y+15&=a\\
2x-2y+3&=b
\end{align*}
To get
$$x=\frac{a+b-18}{4} \quad \text{ and } \quad y=\frac{a-b-12}{4}.$$
So test the factors $a,b$ of $45$ such that these quantities are integers.
\begin{align*}
ab&=45\\
a+b & \equiv 2 \pmod{4}\\
a-b & \equiv 0 \pmod{4}\\
\end{align*}
Hopefully you can take it from here and see *for example* $a=9,b=5$ is a solution.

Comment: The title equation has been changed since your answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan I just added some stuff for the modified question.

Comment: I apologize for this mistake.

Comment: @Shromi No worries. Typos are very common. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $45=ab$ has 12 solutions.  For each one you may solve \begin{equation}2x+2y+15=a\\2x-2y+3=b\end{equation} to obtain all 12 solutions.

To speed things up you could note that replacing any $x$ with $-9-x$ and fixing $y$, or replacing $y$ with $-6-y$ and fixing $x$ transforms one solution into another, so there are just 3 groups of 4 solutions to find.

Comment: Just realised this solution is essentially the same as what was already there.  Tried to downvote, but it turns out you cannot do this.